# Sharing file securely between native android process and Android Java application

Tags: android, security

I need to share the file securely between native Android process and one Android Java application.

How can I make sure that the file is shared securely so that the root access also wont be able to read it?

Regards,

Sameer Joshi

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to hide it from a root process. Root could inject code into the Java part of the app that grabs the data, no matter how you transmit it. Just have a look at Xposed.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to not store it on file system like through pipe or something?

Comment: Well, you can make it harder for an attacker but in the end, he can always inject Java code which makes it **impossible** to build 100% secure apps